# Android - Get isChecked() for items in AlertDialog?

Tags: java, android, dialog

I created an `AlertDialog` with checkbox items using `setMultiChoiceItems()`. I added a `setPositiveButton()` and `setNegativeButton()` to the Dialog.

When I press the positive button, I want to iterate through the list of items in the Dialog and determine if each one is checked or not. But it doesn't appear there is any obvious way to do this.

I can get the list of items from this:

```
alertDialog.getListView().getItemAtPosition(n);
```

but I can't checked if the item `isChecked()` or anything like that. About all I can do it print out the Text using `.toString()`.

The only other way to do what I want, is to use the `onMultiChoiceClickListener().onClick()` to listen for when an item is checked, and then determine which item is clicked and if it's checked or not. I then need to store this info in an array or list and then when the positive button is pressed, I need to refer to this array to determine which is checked and which is not. I know that this method will work, but is there a programmatic way to check if an item is checked or not after the fact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my answer. I was just looking for the wrong method.

**Solution**
    `alertDialog.getListView().isItemChecked(position);`

**Update. This is buggy**

I spoke too soon. I think I discovered an Android bug with this method. If you have a high number of items in your list, to the point that the list is scrollable and you have to scroll down the list to see them, items come back as being UNCHECKED even if they are checked by default if the item has not scrolled onto the screen yet. I reported it [here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21307).

Answer (score 2):

Easiest and probably dirtiest answer is to cast to a CheckBox
    ((CheckBox)alertDialog.getListView().getItemAtPosition(n)).isChecked();  //do an instanceof check before the cast to avoid a ClassCastException

The other way is to extend alert dialog (add a method that will return the selected checkboxes) or pass in an object (bundle or whatnot that holds the array or list)that will hold the selected items for you so either way in this case you will need to use the onMultiChoiceClickListener().onClick().  You wouldn't need to check it after the fact in the array just remove from the array if the checkbox is unchecked and add if it is checked in the onClick method.  Or you could use a map (multimap see: google guava or apache) that has a selected and notselected as the key and the checkbox (preferably the backing object) as the value.

HTH